# Preventing managed objects from being re-faulted by Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have an object graph that models a tree structure. I wish to fetch (without faults) a single, complete tree structure **and** have it remain in the managed object context at my (the user's) discretion for modification and calculations based upon the tree's structure. The objects in the structure would also maintain references to unmanaged objects for the duration of their time in the MOC.

*Is this possible? If so, in what ways can it be accomplished?*

Note: I realize this is a slight misuse of Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using Core Data directly, it will always try to clear memory if there's a memory warning.

However, if you always want it in memory you could create a wrapper object i.e.

```
@class MyObject {
  NSManagedObject *thisIsWhatIRepresent;

  NSString *someProperty;
}

- (id)initWithManagedObject:(NSMagagedObject *)managedObject;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *someProperty;

@end
```

When you init this, you copy all the properties from the managed object into this object's properties. then it doesn't matter if your managed object gets faulted out - this object has a copy of the data.

You would have to make sure that any changes to your object will also change the mananged object as well though you could wait until you have a few changes and save them all at once?

NOTE: This is a messy solution. My advice is to use Core Data as it's intended or not at all :)

Comment: I had thought of something similar, and quickly arrived at the same conclusion you did: it's messy. 

"My advice is to use Core Data as it's intended or not at all :)"...I figured I would get at least one response like this :-)

Comment: Until I saw the NOTE at the bottom of your question, that would have been the entirety of my answer ;) I think that you're going to end up with a messy solution no matter what, sorry!